# how to update a serialized bin file without earase the data that already saved?

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to run a program that saves object by serializing it to a bin file.
The problem is, when I serialize one object to a new file, I can't add to the same file same object without erasing it. 
Is there any method to serialize objects with the same type one by one, and then deserialized a list of the object?

this is the object saving:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UserHandler.saveUser("or kandabi", "2133", "board 1");
    UserHandler.saveUser("dana waizer", "21343", "board 2");
    UserHandler.saveUser("elad", "4353", "board 3");
}
```

this is the methods for saving the object

```
public static void saveUser(String userName,String password,String boardId)
{
    DalUser u = new DalUser(userName, password, boardId);
    if (!File.Exists("userData.bin"))
    {
        Stream myFileStream = File.Create("userData.bin");
        BinaryFormatter serializes = new BinaryFormatter();
        serializes.Serialize(myFileStream, u);
        myFileStream.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Stream myFileStream = File.OpenRead("userData.bin");
        BinaryFormatter serializes = new BinaryFormatter();
        serializes.Serialize(myFileStream, u);
        myFileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

I expected that the data whould saved in the same "userData.bin" file, but there was an exception that the stream could not be opened for writing.

Comment: The problem is when you deserialize you don't know where each object ends.  Now if you add a byte count before each block when serializing then you can read when deserialize so you know where each block ends.

Comment: You open the file for reading in your `else` part, but your main issue is the one that jdweng talks about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileStream` and `FileMode.Append`. Then you are able to add any object to your file and later you can read them as a list. Change your code to the following:

```
public static void saveUser(String userName, String password, String boardId)
{
    DalUser u = new DalUser(userName, password, boardId);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("userData.bin", FileMode.Append))
    {
        var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, u);
    }
}

public static List<DalUser> readUsers()
{
    if (!File.Exists("userData.bin"))
        return null;
    var list = new List<DalUser>();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("userData.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
        {
            list.Add((DalUser)bFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```